# Can fabric-node-sdk 1.2 be used with a Fabric 1.1 network?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I get the below error when I try to create channel on a Fabric 1.1. Is there a workaround to use the 1.2 SDK for a Fabric 1.1 network?

```
 [2018-08-01 11:48:41.498] [DEBUG] Helper - [NetworkConfig101.js]: _addPeersToChannel - peer1.org2.example.com - grpcs://x.x.x.x:8056
    [2018-08-01 11:48:41.498] [DEBUG] Helper - [NetworkConfig101.js]: getOrderer - name orderer.example.com
    [2018-08-01 11:48:41.504] [DEBUG] Helper - [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: ecdsa signature:  Signature {
      r: <BN: 18641b0400ca8526210ae69af03db05877e3e6a1109bcbae94b716259a973b11>,
      s: <BN: 6c4d65ef6d4088975f2d145b93c1420d5e15866da96733b213e3d699f0c9e2a9>,
      recoveryParam: 1 }
    [2018-08-01 11:48:41.569] [ERROR] Create-Channel - Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Sent message larger than max (2241 vs. 15)
        at createStatusError (D:\dev\hyperledger\fabric-samples-sdk\fabric-sdk-util\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client.js:64:15)
        at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (D:\dev\hyperledger\fabric-samples-sdk\fabric-sdk-util\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client.js:270:19)
        at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (D:\dev\hyperledger\fabric-samples-sdk\fabric-sdk-util\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client.js:236:8)
        at readCallback (D:\dev\hyperledger\fabric-samples-sdk\fabric-sdk-util\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client.js:296:12)
    (node:1552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to initialize the channel: Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Sent message larger than max (2241 vs. 15)
        at Object.createChannel (D:\dev\hyperledger\fabric-samples-sdk\fabric-sdk-util\sdk-util\create-channel.js:66:9)
        at <anonymous>
    (node:1552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:1552) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove below line from network-config.yaml file. This file is used to load the connection config.

```
 grpc-max-send-message-length: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

The most critical part of sdk-node change from 1.1 to 1.2 is the removal of old eventHub library and migration to use channelEventHub instead.

It looks as a breaking change because:

- `ChannelEventHub` binds to channel and peer, it uses port 7051 ,not
  port 7053 anymore
- connection mechanism has some minor change, it is recommended to explicitly call `channelEventHub.connect()` before registering listeners.